# Z axis support to view an UIView

Tags: ios, cocos3d

I want to place an UIView in Z axis forward from the main camera view. I have added code like below. I am trying with CATransform3DTranslate, but JAPanoView (its an uiview) doesn't display in Z axis value mentioned to be in forward to the camera view. Could someone please advise, how can i achieve it?

```
    -(void) initializeScene {

    // Create the camera, place it back a bit, and add it to the scene
    CC3Camera* cam = [CC3Camera nodeWithName: @"Camera"];
    cam.location = cc3v( 0.0, 0.0, 12.0 );
    [self addChild: cam];

    // Create a light, place it back and to the left at a specific
    // position (not just directional lighting), and add it to the scene
    CC3Light* lamp = [CC3Light nodeWithName: @"Lamp"];
    lamp.location = cc3v( 0.0, 40.0, 0.0 );
    lamp.isDirectionalOnly = NO;
    [cam addChild: lamp];

    // JAPanoView IS AN UIVIEW
    JAPanoView *panoView=[[JAPanoView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    //self.view=panoView;
    panoView.delegate=self;
    [panoView setFrontImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_front.png"] rightImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_right.png"] backImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_back.png"] leftImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_left.png"] topImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_up.png"] bottomImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Home_down.png"]];

    CATransform3D _3Dt = CATransform3DIdentity;
    _3Dt = CATransform3DTranslate(_3Dt, 0, 0, -30);
    panoView.layer.transform = _3Dt;

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:panoView];

    // Create OpenGL ES buffers for the vertex arrays to keep things fast and efficient,
    // and to save memory, release the vertex data in main memory because it is now redundant.
    [self createGLBuffers];
    [self releaseRedundantData];
}
```

Comment: Try it with a regular UIButton. It may not be possible to perform 3D transformations on UIViews in general. Or try applying the transform after adding the view. That's the 2 things I'd try.

Comment: I tried transform after adding in the view, but it is not solving.

Comment: my sample project is here-> https://www.hightail.com/download/bWJyYUluT2IzS3FLRmNUQw

Comment: Have you tried a regular UIButton? I have never tried it myself but I wouldn't be too surprised if UIViews simply can not be translated in 3 dimensions - after all they're 2D user interface views.

Comment: This is what trying to achieve.I am trying to use the sample panorama class ‘JAPanoView’, which i got from open source link https://bitbucket.org/javieralonso/japanoview.
So, I have to provide 6 images such as for front, back, left, right, top and bottom to support panorama rotation using ‘CATransform3DTranslate’ and ‘CATransform3DRotate’ by this panorama viewer UIView class. I want to add this logic in Cocos3d project. Because, i want to add a 3d model further into this panorama view. Is it possible to add a 3d model on top of 2d images on UIView in Cocos3d based project?

Comment: Here is my query-> http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/uiview-in-z-axis-view/#post-409722

Comment: Ok, so this would only work with the JAPanoView in the background. For that you have to follow the guides (google or check SO) that show how to enable UIViews in the background of a cocos2d app. Basic procedure is to make the cocos2d view transparent (opaque = NO) with color set to UIColor clearColor and changing the CCGLView framebuffer format to RGBA8888 (32 bit with alpha). Then you can have the panoramic view in the bg and 3d models in the foreground, though it'll be difficult to synchronize them.

Answer (score 1):

The z-order of UIViews is the order of them in their superview's subviews property. To have on subview in front of another you can user you can simple addSubview them in the correct order, place them in the XIB file in this order or use bringSubviewToFront.